# TensorFlow C++ Automatic Differentiation from Graph

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, bazel, automatic-differentiation

I have use Bazelisk to compile the Tensorflow headers using `install_headers` build target and the library using the `cc_tensorflow` target. I want to do the following in C++:

```py
import tensorflow as tf 

x = tf.Variable(3.0)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(x)
    y = x ** 2

grad = tape.gradient(y, x)
print(grad)
```

I can't find a single, complete guide to do this. I have seen things about the `GradientRegistery` and debug gradients but no implementation to base my work on. Any help about how to do this would be truly appreciated. If this is the incorrect place for the question, please direct me to the correct place to ask!